# functions, variable and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 8 search filters user can choose. When user clicks on filter it opens options for this filter. When user clicks out, the function `hideFilterSearch()` is triggered. I have problem about understanding of scope for variable formData (see below).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var formData = $("form").serialize();
});

function hideFilterSearch() {
    console.log(formData);
    $(".filters").hide();
    newFormData = $("form").serialize();
    if (formData != newFormData) {
        //newFormData is sent with ajax and search results are updates
    }
    formData = $("form").serialize();  
}

//show, hide filter changer
$('body').click(function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('.filter').length) {        
        hideFilterChanger();
    };
});
```

Console log gives me empty string in this case. I tried also to send `formData` as argument `()hideFilterSearch(formData)`, but then the problem is `formData` won't be updated. I am not sure what is the correct way to pass `formData` to function, but still update it's value inside function when it is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use global variable.As  formData  variable  in local scope,you can't accesss it in antother function.

Change your code to the following

```
window.formData = $("form").serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions can return values. Pass formData and return the updated one from the function. You can then assign it in hideFilterChanged.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var formData = $("form").serialize();

 function hideFilterSearch(formData){
     console.log(formData);
     $(".filters").hide();
     newFormData = $("form").serialize();
     if(formData!=newFormData){
       //newFormData is sent with ajax and search results are updates
     }
     return $("form").serialize();  
   }

   //show, hide filter changer
   $('body').click(function(event) {
     if (!$(event.target).closest('.filter').length) {        
         formData = hideFilterChanger(formData);
     };
   });
});
```